# Create matrix by indices from text file in Python

Tags: python, matrix

I have the following problem, I have a matrix generated by another program and written to a txt file, the file looks like this: ( I only included part of the matrix, total is 36 lines)

```
 1     1   7.225655E+03
 1     2   0.000000E+00
 1     3   0.000000E+00
 1     4   0.000000E+00
 1     5   2.384466E+04
 1     6   0.000000E+00
 2     1   0.000000E+00
 2     2   7.225655E+03         .
          .
          .
 5     5   4.175514E+06
 5     6   0.000000E+00
 6     1   0.000000E+00
 6     2  -2.829306E+03
 6     3   0.000000E+00
 6     4   0.000000E+00
 6     5   0.000000E+00
 6     6   3.916341E+06
```

I loaded this matrix already in a numpy array but now I would like to write a simple function which puts the values in a 6x6 matrix according to the indices on the first two columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `a` is the tree-column matrix you've read from the file, the following should do it:

```
>>> m = np.zeros((6,6))
>>> for row, col, val in a:
...    m[row - 1, col - 1] = val
```